# Requirejs' order does not work with priority config and CDN dependencies

Tags: cdn, requirejs

The following `main.js` code do not respect the order of priorities (sometimes `underscore.js` is not loaded when `backbone.js` needs it):

```
require({
    baseUrl:'/scripts',
    priority:[
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js",
        "http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js",
        "http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"
    ]
    },["src/app"], 
    function (app) {
        app.start();
});
```

Adding `order!` before those CDN dependencies fails with a `order.js not found` error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently updated the RequireJS docs, but I have not pushed the change to the site yet:

The "priority" configuration cannot load resources loaded by plugins. So to accomplish what you are trying to do, you can just nest require() calls, which will give you the behavior you want:

```
require(
    {
        baseUrl:'/scripts'
    },
    [
        "require",
        "order!http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js",
        "order!http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js",
        "order!http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js",
        "order!http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"

    ], 
    function (require) {
        require(["src/app"], function (app) {
            app.start();
        });
    }
);
```

This assumes you have the order plugin in the /scripts/order.js location.

Comment: This works perfectly. It is possible to import the `order` plugin and `RequireJS` too with a CDN address?

Comment: Great to hear. I am not aware of both order.js and require.js being on a CDN at the moment, although I do want to lobby for at least require.js once the 1.0 release is done. require.js is up on http://www.cdnjs.com but I do not have any data on how reliable it is, or the people that back that CDN. I like what they are trying to do though.

Comment: Why do you need nested require calls? couldn't we just include order!src/app in the dependencies array? Thanks

Comment: Thomas from cdnjs.com chiming in here.   We are partnered with a company called cloudflare.com which has doubled up our reliability.   But I do believe that if things can go wrong they will hence why I opened a thread on google groups(https://groups.google.com/group/requirejs/browse_thread/thread/6c5811b1c229df86).   Hopefully someone can write a detailed solution for using a CDN and fall back local scripts using require.js