# Sourcing jQuery from a CDN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, requirejs

I am using require JS and want to know the best method to use a CDN version of jQuery. I hear the 1.7 version is "AMD" which is supposed to help but can't find a straight example. Hope some RequireJS gurus can help me out.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

jQuery 1.7 registers itself as an AMD module by the name of 'jquery', so you need to create a mapping for 'jquery' using the paths config:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery' : 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min'
  }
});

require(['jquery'], function($) {
  //$ points to jQuery
});
```

Note however that RequireJS loads modules asynchronously and **out of order**, so if you have jQuery plugins you want to use that are not wrapped in `define(['jquery'], function ($){ /* plugin code goes here */ });` calls, the plugin could execute before jQuery is loaded.

See the [require-jquery](https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery) project's README on ways to deal with files that depend on jQuery but do not wrap themselves in `define()` calls.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand now this module malarky now. Could you please explain why underscore doesn't get loaded in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/sCFwE/7/? I can see in the source that it has a 'define' call with the name 'underscore' at line 61. https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js

Comment: How can I easily see what modules have been defined? eg. `console.log(definedModules);`

Comment: @pagewil I removed the ".js" from underscore's path mapping.  Modules don't use file extensions, typically.  It seems that was the culprit: http://jsfiddle.net/unscriptable/sCFwE/44/

Comment: In regards to seeing which module have been defined: all AMD loaders use different mechanisms to expose their inner details, such as their cache of modules. Pinging @jrburke on that one. :)

Comment: @unscriptable you bloody legend you!

Comment: @unscriptable so now if I want to share both 'jquery' and 'underscore' between modules (eg. main1.js, main2.js etc) I will have to exclude it from the optimization process right? Don't want these libraries getting bundled into my built JS files :S

Comment: @pagewil possibly. if you plan to reference those on CDNs, then, yes, you'll want to exclude them from being built into your optimized files.  if you plan to host those files locally, then there are several options for building/optimizing.  just get it running first, then explore your options. :)

Comment: Here is the doc link on how to exclude a path from the optimization process: http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty

Answer (score 9):

@jrburke's answer does not work for me. According to the [RequireJS api doc](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths), you should not include the file extension in the path. So here is the working code:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min'
    }
});

require(['jquery'], function($) {
    //$ points to jQuery
});
```

I have a working example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/murrayju/FdKTn/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think @jrburke is the author of require.js, so chances are he's got it right.

Comment: I also had to remove ".js" from the paths config mapping in the example given above to make it work.

Comment: @ZachL, did you look at my jsfiddle? Just add in the `.js`, and you'll see that it doesn't work. This might be something that changed in some version of requirejs, because the documentation is inconsistent about when to remove the `.js`.

Comment: @murrayju yup. You got it right. Looking into the edits on @jrburke's post, so did he, but someone (incorrectly) editted the `.js` into it. Editting it back out now...

Answer (score 3):

You can include it as a dependency for a module but it's a little flakey. e.g

```
define([
"order!http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"
], function($) {
})
```

It's not so good for 2 reasons

1) the jquery file itself isn't a module so the `$` you get from the function won't be jquery

2) the `order!` plugin doesn't work well with CDN versions of scripts.  See [Requirejs' order does not work with priority config and CDN dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135259/requirejs-order-does-not-work-with-priority-config-and-cdn-dependencies)

I haven't had the chance to use this in a 'real' project yet because we haven't upgraded yet, but from my tests i've found that the best way is to include jquery in a script tag, then it works great as a dependency to your modules.  Hopefully the following small sample will be helpful:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index2</title>
    <script src="../../scripts/libraries/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/libraries/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"">

        require(
            {baseUrl: 'scripts'}, 
            ['jquery'], 
            function (dollarSign) {
                console.log(dollarSign('div').html('hi'));
            });       
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. Underneath your baseUrl line you have ['jquery'] how does require know that that refers to the script you included above? If it is referring to the 'jQuery' window object should it not be written as 'jQuery' not 'jquery'?

Comment: @timeDunham I have mocked up you example as a Fiddle here and it works http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/BLaLq/1/ still don't understand where require gets the jQuery object from?!

Comment: how would it work for underscore like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/BLaLq/2/

Comment: Q1) @pagewil It gets the jQuery object because jquery registers itself as an AMD module (line 970 of jquery 1.7 unminified version).

Comment: timDunham: So - jquery does calls define so it does registers itself as a module and does returns jQuery object back. Why are you saying that it's not a module?

Comment: well I probably used the wrong terminology.  how it differs is that if you just refer to the jquery file in your require(...) statement it won't return a reference to the jquery object.

Comment: timDunham: Also from jquery 1.7 : "Now an AMD-compliant loader can load an unmodified version of jQuery 1.7 from a CDN such as Google’s or Microsoft’s."

Comment: ya--from your comments I'm thinking that I may have been missing stuff.  As I mentioned, I've only been using this in some sample/test projects and I may not be using it right.  From what you're saying it *should* just pull it in but it hasn't worked for me.  Now I'm going to have to see if I've been doing something wrong.

Comment: @Stann can you please demonstrate an example based on one of the Fiddles I have posted? :)

Comment: @pagewil: Honestly - I'm trying to figure it out myself. Whole AMD concept is a bit new. I'll post smthg if/when I wrap by brains around it.

Comment: here's a fiddle that is probably better than my original answer: http://jsfiddle.net/timdunham/sCFwE/

Comment: there is a post talking about loading jquery 1.7 and it sorta explains things: https://groups.google.com/group/requirejs/browse_thread/thread/e7532b7e3013bc62 .   But the way it's specified in last timDunham example is a bit weird. I wonder if there is another way.

Comment: @timDunham surely this should work but doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/sCFwE/4/

Comment: Trying to include underscore in a similar way and fails: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/sCFwE/7/

Comment: jquery 1.7 now registers itself as an AMD module.  Don't use the order! plugin or a separate script element with jquery 1.7.  See James Burke's answer to this question.

Comment: You have to spell the module name correctly in the paths config or the AMD loader can't verify that it loaded the correct module.  In this fiddle, the module name is intentionally misspelled, so requirejs can't make sens of it: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/sCFwE/4/  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unscriptable/JbUrJ/

Comment: hey guys--sorry went MIA for a while.  @pagewil about the fiddle with 'jqueryyyy'... the reason it doesn't work is that the jquery specifically registers itself (the define call) with 'jquery' so when you request jqueryyy it goes and loads the file and when it's done it expects that there is a module loaded named 'jqueryyy' but doesn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's recommend use [Protocol-relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) for jQuery CDN.
And second, use array in value with CDN and local places for load local file if CND is dead. You can use as many CDNs urls you want. Do not afraid, it dosn't want load second file from local place if successfully download it from CDN.

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min', 'lib/jquery-1.10.2.min']
  }
});
```