# Requirejs doesn't load jquery1.7 from CDN as module

Tags: php, jquery, requirejs, js-amd

I need to load jQuery1.7 as module, I've seen this code of [@jrburke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126372/jrburke):

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery' : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min'
  }
});

require(['jquery'], function($) {
  //$ points to jQuery
});
```

It's not very useful for me, because all `.js` name are generated by server-side, I got them from php-array.

So, I wrote this:

```
require(['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js'],
        function($) {
  //$ points to jQuery
});
```

But `$` is null inside this function.

**UPDATE**:

Here is my php-template that render my js-scripts for this page:

```
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/1.0.1/minified/require.js">
</script>

<script> 
    require([
        <?php echo "'". implode("',\n\t'", $this->scripts) . "'\n"; ?>
    ], function($){

        console.warn ($); // null ;(

        // loaded jQuery
        window.$ = $;

        // Load main client script for this page
        boot( '<?php echo $this->eprint($this->content_page); ?>' );

    });
</script>
```

and it is my php-array for this page (page `index`):

```
$scripts = array(
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js',
    'http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js',
    '/js/libs/jquery.history.js?v=1321687090',
    '/js/libs/coolclock.js?v=1321629683',
    '/js/libs/excanvas.js?v=1321629683',
    '/js/client.modules.js?v=1321703735',
    '/js/client.all.js?v=1322512192',
    '/js/boot.js?v=1322512037',
    '/js/client.index.js?v=1321689884'
);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sourcing jQuery from a CDN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070959/sourcing-jquery-from-a-cdn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your php array of the form:

```
$jquery = array (
   'jQuery' => 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js'
);
```

Then try:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: <?php echo json_encode($jquery) ?>
});

require(['jquery'], function($) {
  //$ points to jQuery
});
```

Comment: @Innuendo just make it so they are, and your life will be magically easier :-)

Comment: So I can add every element of my array in `paths` prop of `requirejs.config` ? it's normal, that not all of them are in form of modules, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `modules`

Comment: I mean scripts that `requirejs` gets as modules. These scripts are wrapped in structure: `define('Name', function(){ return function Name(){}  });` `jquery1.7` has this wrap in itself.

Comment: Duplicate of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070959/sourcing-jquery-from-a-cdn